# Tate's theorem for Hall subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$. Take $P\le V\le G$. Tate's theorem states that if $V\cap A^p(G)=A^p(V)$, then $V\cap O^p(G)=O^p(V)$.

Now let $H$ be a Hall $\omega-$subgroup of $G$ for $\omega$ a set of primes and $H\le V\le G$. Is it true that if $V\cap A^{\omega}(G)=A^{\omega}(V)$, then $V\cap O^{\omega}(G)=O^{\omega}(V)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $G = {\rm AGL}(1,7)$ (order $42$), $\omega = \{2,7\}$, and $H=V = O_\omega(G)$, which is dihedral of order $14$.

Then $A^\omega(G) = O^\omega(G)$ has order $21$ with $V \cap A^\omega(G) = A^\omega(V)$ of order $7$, but $O^\omega(V) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks very much Derek. I will look into that counter-example. I have the intuition that the result is true if $H$ is nilpotent. Do you have a counter-example for that case too?

Comment: Yes I would guess that it is true if there is a nilpotent Hall subgroup. I think the result in that case follows by applying Tate's theorem to each individual prime.

Comment: I agree. I was working on a complicated proof using transfer but it is much more efficient and intuitive the way you recommend. Thanks very much !

Comment: This being said, how do you show that $V\cap A^{\omega}(G)=A^{\omega}(V)$ implies that $V\cap A^p(G)=A^p(V)$ for every $p\in \omega$ ?